# Display fraction of innerHTML output on every odd/second loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, innerhtml

Quite new to Stack Overflow and new enough to javascript also.
Hope the issue is not to unclear on my behalf for people to understand.

I have an issue where I have a for loop which displays my content on every loop and that was the way I needed it to display initially, it was also in the perfect format for display.

I now have an issue where I want one part of my innerHTML output 'myArr[i]' to only display on every odd loop and not on the even loops while the rest still displays on every loop...

Any suggestions?

```js
var clicks = 0;
document.getElementById("arrowLink").innerHTML.value = clicks; // clickable arrow

document.getElementById("arrowLink").addEventListener("click", function()
  {
  if (clicks < 1)
    {
    for(var i=0; i < displayArr1.length; i++)
      {
      middleEndpoints.innerHTML +=
        "<div class='d-flex justify-content-center'>"+
          "<div class='p-2'>"+
              "<p>Abc</p>"+
          "</div>"+
        
// HOW DO I GET THE BELOW PART OF MY CODE TO ONLY DISPLAY ON EVERY ODD OR SECOND LOOP?
 
        "<div class='row'>"+
          "<div class='col-sm-1 align-self-center'>"+
            "<p style='margin-bottom: 0;'>" + myArr[i] + "</p>"+
          "</div>"+

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

          "<div class='col-sm-10 align-self-center'>"+
            "<p class='midLine'>&#8645;</p>"+
          "</div>"+
        "</div>"; 
      }
      clicks += 1;
    }
  });
```

Comment: 1. No need to shout 2. click the `[<>]` snippet editor to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```js
document.getElementById("arrowLink").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (clicks >= 1) return
  clicks++;
  const html = [];
  displayArr1.forEach((item, i) => {
    html.push(`<div class='d-flex justify-content-center'>
        <div class='p-2'>
        <p>Abc</p>
        </div>`);
    if (i % 2) {
      html.push(`<div class='row'>
            <div class='col-sm-1 align-self-center'>
            <p style='margin-bottom: 0;'>${myArr[i]}</p>
            </div>`);
    }
    html.push(`<div class='col-sm-10 align-self-center'>
        <p class='midLine'>&#8645;</p>
        </div>
        </div>`)
  });
  middleEndpoints.innerHTML=html.join("");
  clicks += 1;
});
```

Comment: This worked perfect, helped a lot, I'll make the code reproducible next time, with no shouting haha, apologies.. thanks mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

> Use the modulus % operator to determine if a number if odd or even in
> JavaScript.

An even number is a number which is divisible by 2. Therefore, perform %2 operation on the given number, if the result is 0 then the given number is even else given number is odd.

```
var clicks = 0;
document.getElementById("arrowLink").innerHTML.value = clicks; // clickable arrow
document.getElementById("arrowLink").addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (clicks < 1) {
        for(var i=0; i < displayArr1.length; i++) {
            middleEndpoints.innerHTML +=
                "<div class='d-flex justify-content-center'>"+
                    "<div class='p-2'>"+
                        "<p>Abc</p>"+
                    "</div>";
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
            middleEndpoints.innerHTML +=
                   "<div class='row'>"+
                        "<div class='col-sm-1 align-self-center'></div>"+
                        "<p style='margin-bottom: 0;'>" + myArr[i] + "</p>"+
                    "</div>";
            }
            middleEndpoints.innerHTML +=
                    "<div class='col-sm-10 align-self-center'>"+
                        "<p class='midLine'>&#8645;</p>"+
                    "</div>"+
                "</div>"; 
        }
        clicks += 1;
    }
});
```